# Django Cannot Resolve Related Model

Tags: python, django, migration, models

I just added a new model called "Purchaser" into an app called "standard". I run the makemigrations and everything is hunky dory and then I try to run migrate and I get the following error:

```
    Running migrations:
  Applying tracking.0002_auto_20180418_1909...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 122, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 481, in alter_field
    new_db_params = new_field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 966, in db_parameters
    return {"type": self.db_type(connection), "check": self.db_check(connection)}
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 963, in db_type
    return self.target_field.rel_db_type(connection=connection)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 877, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 634, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 621, in related_fields
    self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 606, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'standard.Purchaser' cannot be resolved
```

Here's the model for Purchaser:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template import loader
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from comp.models import ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

TIME_CHOICES = (
    (8.0,'8:00 AM'),
    (8.5,'8:30 AM'),
    (9.0,'9:00 AM'),
    (9.5,'9:30 AM'),
    (10.0,'10:00 AM'),
    (10.5,'10:30 AM'),
    (11.0,'11:00 AM'),
    (11.5,'11:30 AM'),
    (12.0,'12:00 PM'),
    (12.5,'12:30 PM'),
    (13.0,'1:00 PM'),
    (13.5,'1:30 PM'),
    (14.0,'2:00 PM'),
    (14.5,'2:30 PM'),
    (15.0,'3:00 PM'),
    (15.5,'3:30 PM'),
    (16.0,'4:00 PM'),
    (16.5,'4:30 PM'),
    (17.0,'5:00 PM'),
    (17.5,'5:30 PM'),
)

class Purchaser(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    #entity = models.ForeignKey('comp.Entity', blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey('comp.Company', related_name='company_employee', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    #brand = models.OneToOneField('comp.Brand', related_name='employee', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=64) 
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    company_type = models.IntegerField(choices=ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    time_zone = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], blank=True, max_length=64)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='employees', blank=True, null=True)
    cover_image = models.ImageField('Cover Image', upload_to='employees', blank=True, null=True, help_text='A 1300 width by 300 height top cover image.')
    linkedin_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    pay_token = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    paid_till_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    linkedin_url = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    facebook_url = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    twitter_url = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    company_url = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    registered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    subscription_current = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #membership = models.IntegerField(choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES)
    coupon = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True) 
    terms = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    invoice_requested = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    detail_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    categories_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    jobs_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    education_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    boards_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    articles_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    invite_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.user.get_full_name()

    def username_email(self):
        return self.user.email

    def full_name(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name

    def first_name(self):
        return self.user.first_name

    def last_name(self):
        return self.user.last_name



    def domain_from_email(self):
        email = self.user.email
        if 'aol' in email or 'gmail' in email or 'yahoo' in email or 'hotmail' in email or 'outlook' in email or 'live' in email:
            return None
        else:
            return email.split('@')[1]

    def company_domain(self):
        if self.company_url:
            domain = ''
            if '//' in self.company_url:
                domain = self.company_url.split('//')[1]
            if '/' in domain:
                domain = domain.split('/', 1)[0]
            if 'www.' in domain:
                domain = domain.split('www.')[0]  
            return domain 
        else:
            return self.domain_from_email()

#     def url_pretty(self):
#         return self.url.split('//', 1)[-1]

    def fb_url_pretty(self):
        if self.facebook_url:
            if 'www' in self.facebook_url:
                return self.facebook_url.split('www.', 1)[-1]
            return self.facebook_url.split('//', 1)[-1]

    def tw_url_pretty(self):
        if self.twitter_url:
            if 'www' in self.twitter_url:
                return self.twitter_url.split('www.', 1)[-1]
            return self.twitter_url.split('//', 1)[-1]

    def li_url_pretty(self):
        if self.linkedin_url:
            if 'www' in self.linked_url:
                return self.linked_url.split('www.', 1)[-1]
            return self.linkedin_url.split('//', 1)[-1]

    def entity_type(self):
        if self.company:
            return self.company.entity_type
        else:
            return None

    def is_exchange_provider(self):
        return self.user.groups.filter(name='Exchange Provider').exists()

    def is_exchange_startup(self):
        return self.user.groups.filter(name='Exchange Startup').exists()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Person"





ACTION_CHOICES = (
    (0,'viewed-profile'),
    (1,'contact-click'),
    (2,'contact'),
    (3,'entity-posted'),
    (4,'viewed-entity-feed'),
    (5,'report-results-reviewed'),
    (6,'entity-bookmarked'),
    (7,'entity-connected'),
    (8,'entity-note-taken'),
    (9,'entity-followed'),
    (10,'remove-bookmark'),
    (11,'note-edited'),
    (12,'entity-unfollowed'),
    (13,'survey-module-edited'),
    (14,'matching-params-edited'),
    (15,'new-match'),
    (16,'remove-match'),
    (17,'searched'),
    (18,'completed-review'),
    (19,'survey-module-completed'),
    (20,'viewed-article'),
    (21,'invited-colleague'),
    (22,'analytics-query'),
    (23,'viewed-page'),
    (24,'viewed-question')
)


# class TempEmployeeEntity(models.Model):  
#     entity = models.ForeignKey('comp.Entity')
#     employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)

class Transaction(models.Model):  
    #employee = models.ForeignKey(Purchaser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entity = models.ForeignKey('comp.Entity', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    action = models.IntegerField(choices=ACTION_CHOICES)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):  
        try:
            if self.entity.name:
                return self.get_action_display() + ' ' + self.entity.name
            else:
                return self.get_action_display()
        except:
            return self.get_action_display()

class InquiryEmail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField()
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def send(self):

        variables = {
            'name': self.name,
            'message': self.message,
            'email':self.email,

        }

        subject = "[Innovator's Edge] Contact"
        template = loader.get_template('standard/email/inquiry-email.html')

        html_content = template.render(variables)
        text_content = strip_tags(html_content)

        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [settings.DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL])
        if self.site.id == 2:
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [settings.DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL], ['info@insurancethoughtleadership.com'])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        msg.send()
        self.sent = True
        self.save()

class InviteEmail(models.Model):
    #employee = models.ForeignKey(Purchaser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def send(self):

        context = {
            'employee': self.employee,
            'site_long_name':settings.SITE_LONG_NAME,
            'site_url':settings.SITE_URL,
            'reply_email':settings.DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL,
        }

        subject = 'Invitation To Join ' + settings.SITE_LONG_NAME
        template = loader.get_template('standard/email/invite-email.html')

        html_content = template.render(context)
        text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [self.email])

        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        msg.send()
        self.sent = True
        self.save()

class ContactEmail(models.Model):
    #employee = models.ForeignKey(Purchaser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entity = models.ForeignKey('comp.Entity', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def send(self):

        variables = {
            'message': self.message,
            'employee':self.employee,
            'entity':self.entity,
        }

        subject = '['+settings.SITE_LONG_NAME+'] Contact Request From: '+self.employee.user.get_full_name()
        template = loader.get_template('standard/email/contact-email.html')

        html_content = template.render(variables)
        text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [self.employee.user.email], [settings.DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL])

        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        msg.send()
        self.sent = True
        self.save()


NOTIFICATION_CHOICES = (
    (0,'Invoice'),
    (1,'MMR Request'),
)

class TransactionAlertEmail(models.Model):
    #actor = models.ForeignKey(Purchaser, related_name='actor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    actee = models.ForeignKey('comp.entity', related_name='actee', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    alert_type = models.IntegerField(choices=NOTIFICATION_CHOICES)
    actor_type_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    actee_type_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def send(self):

        title = self.get_alert_type_display() + ' Notification'

        variables = {
            'actor': self.actor,
            'actee': self.actee,
            'actor_type_name':self.actor_type_name,
            'alert_type':self.alert_type,
            'actee_type_name':self.actee_type_name,
            'alert_display':self.get_alert_type_display(),
            'temp_static_url':'https://'+settings.AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN+'/static',
            'host':settings.HOST,
        }

        subject = "[Innovator's Edge] "+title
        template = loader.get_template('standard/email/info-alert-email.html')

        html_content = template.render(variables)
        text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, ['info@insurancethoughtleadership.com'])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        msg.send()
        self.sent = True
        self.save()


class WelcomeEmail(models.Model):
    #employee = models.ForeignKey(Purchaser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def send(self):
        print('sending email')


        variables = {
            'employee': self.employee,
            'temp_static_url':'https://'+settings.AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN+'/static',
            'host':settings.HOST,
        }

        subject = 'Welcome to '+settings.SITE_LONG_NAME
        template = loader.get_template('standard/email/welcome-email.html')

        html_content = template.render(variables)
        text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [self.employee.user.email])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        msg.send()
        self.sent = True
        self.save()



class ResetPasswordEmail(models.Model):
    #employee = models.ForeignKey(Purchaser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request_token = models.CharField(max_length=32,default=get_random_string(length=32), unique=True)
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    valid_date = models.DateTimeField()
    redeemed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def send(self):

        variables = {
            'request_token': self.request_token,
            'temp_static_url':'https://'+settings.AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN+'/static',
            'host':settings.HOST,
        }

        subject = 'Reset Your Password'
        template = loader.get_template('standard/email/forgot-password-email.html')

        html_content = template.render(variables)
        text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
        to_email = self.employee.user.email
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [to_email])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        msg.send()
        self.sent = True
        self.save()
```

And here's the migration where it is added:

```
# Generated by Django 2.0.2 on 2018-04-19 02:09

from django.conf import settings
import django.core.validators
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('for', '0020_auto_20180418_1909'),
        ('match', '0013_auto_20180418_1909'),
        ('direct', '0006_auto_20180418_1909'),
        ('comp', '0074_auto_20180305_1740'),
        ('track', '0002_auto_20180418_1909'),
        ('even', '0040_auto_20180418_1909'),
        ('standard', '0037_auto_20180404_2012'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Purchaser',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('desc', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('job_title', models.CharField(max_length=64)),
                ('company_name', models.CharField(max_length=64)),
                ('company_type', models.IntegerField(blank=True, choices=[(0, 'Startup/Innovator/Insurtech'), (1, 'Provider'), (2, 'Accelerator'), (3, 'Incubator'), (4, 'Rating_agency'), (5, 'Carrier'), (6, 'Regulator'), (7, 'News Source'), (8, 'Trade Association'), (9, 'Reinsurer'), (10, 'TPA'), (11, 'VC'), (12, 'Agent/Broker'), (13, 'Advisory'), (14, 'Consultancy'), (15, 'Investor'), (16, 'person'), (17, 'Other'), (18, 'Technology Provider'), (19, 'Education & Training')], null=True)),
                ('time_zone', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64, null=True)),
                ('phone_number', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64, validators=[django.core.validators.RegexValidator(message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.", regex='^\\+?1?\\d{9,15}$')])),
                ('image', models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='employees')),
                ('cover_image', models.ImageField(blank=True, help_text='A 1300 width by 300 height top cover image.', null=True, upload_to='employees', verbose_name='Cover Image')),
                ('linkedin_id', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('pay_token', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('stripe_customer_id', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('paid_till_date', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('linkedin_url', models.URLField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('facebook_url', models.URLField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('twitter_url', models.URLField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('url', models.URLField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('company_url', models.URLField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('registered', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('subscription_current', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('paid', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('coupon', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64, null=True)),
                ('terms', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('invoice_requested', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('detail_completed', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('categories_completed', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('jobs_completed', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('education_completed', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('boards_completed', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('articles_completed', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('invite_completed', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('updated_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                ('company', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='company_employee', to='comp.Company')),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Person',
            },
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='employ',
            name='brand',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='employ',
            name='company',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='employ',
            name='user',
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='contact',
            name='employee',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='cstandard.Purchaser'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='invite',
            name='employee',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='standard.Purchaser'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='resetpassemail',
            name='employee',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='standard.Purchaser'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='resetpassdemail',
            name='request_token',
            field=models.CharField(default='jN1D4G0qKCpTexaJWhHhil8qAobmzdu8', max_length=32, unique=True),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='transact',
            name='employee',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='standard.Purchaser'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='transactalertemail',
            name='actor',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='actor', to='stanndard.Purchaser'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='welcomeem',
            name='employee',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='standard.Purchaser'),
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='Employ',
        ),
    ]
```

Things I've tried based on internet searches:
     Adding and removing auth_user_model from migration,
     Changing order of apps in settings
Does anyone see the issue? It's driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Format your code.

Comment: If you're talking about the model, I fixed that though it's only one indent.

Comment: Is `Purchaser` a foreignkey in any other model ?

Comment: Yes in this app and others

Comment: That's why it's giving you the error.

Comment: So how do I fix it? Remove the foreignkey relation I have with company?

Comment: I apologize I'm still a django novice

Comment: I posted an answer. Tell me if you are clear.